# C++ book-keeping of all instantiations of a class template

Tags: c++, c++11

In my API I have a class template `template<class T> struct MyType`. The user of my API can instantiate the template `MyType` with several types (e.g. `MyType<int>, MyType<UserType>, MyType<OtherUserType>` . Is it possible at compile time to detect all instantiations? To have something like: `using AllInstantiations = type_list<int, UserType, OtherUserType>`? The reason I ask is, that I want to register these types. And when reading a string, that can be "int", "UserType" or "OtherUserType", I want to lookup at the registered types and find the matching one.

Comment: The usual way to do something like this is to have a static data member, whose initialization registers the instantiation with some global singleton. This doesn't give you a compile-time type list, but a run-time data structure that's fully built before `main` is entered. A type list you envision is impossible, since different instantiations may occur in different translation units and only come together at link time.

Comment: You might be able to do something creative with [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please consider any 'Factory' implementation, that will contains `class ...RegisteredTypes` as `std::tuple<RegisteredTypes...>` arguments. See example:

```
template <class ... RegisteredTypes>
class Factory
{
public:
    using MyRegisteredClassList = std::tuple<MyClass<RegisteredTypes>...>;
    using RegisteredTypesList = std::tuple<RegisteredTypes...>;

    //Specific type creation Factory method - if encapsulation required
    template<class T,  class ...T_Args>
    static inline MyClass<T> createMyClassInstance(T_Args &&...args)
    {
        //TODO add 'static_assert'
        //for check T as 'RegisteredTypesList' and invoke pretty warning here
        return MyClass<T>(std::forward<T_Args>(args)...);
    }

   //TODO add your method for searching 'string' in 'RegisteredTypesList'
   // use c++17 std::apply(), for example
};
```

The drawback of this method, is that you need instantiate the global/static type `Factory<int,OneType,SecondType, ...>` in client code as part of 'registration' procedure. But you can provide & encapsulate  additional required type-processing logic in this Factory.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution/workaround. I think asking the client code to instantiate the Factory type is acceptable. Thanks Sergey!